# Is it possible to use the Google Maps API on multiple pages in the same website?

Tags: javascript, api, maps

I want to use three maps, two on one page and one on another page, all in the same website. I can get one page to work but not the other, it tends to be the first one that I choose to execute in my window.onload function. So I know that there isn't an issue in my code as I can get them all to work, just not at the same time. The only thing I can think of is that maybe it's because i'm using the same API key on each page? If so, how do I get a separate key? Here's my code:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Google Maps
function scaligeroMap() {
var scaligeroLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(45.766281, 10.8088879);

var mapOptions = {
  'center' : scaligeroLocation,
  'zoom' : 17,
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('scaligeroMap'), mapOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        'position' : scaligeroLocation,
        'map' : map,
        'title' : 'Castello Scaligero'
    });

//////////////////////////////////////////////Pop up containing address when marker is clicked
var popupContent = 'Castello Malcesine:<br>';
popupContent += 'Via Castello Scaligero, 39<br>';
popupContent += '37018 Malcesine Verona<br>';
popupContent += 'Italy';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: popupContent,
  maxWidth: 200
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
});

}

function alCorsaroMap() {
var alCorsaroLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(45.7658856, 10.8099179);

var mapOptions = {
  'center' : alCorsaroLocation,
  'zoom' : 17,
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('alCorsaroMap'), mapOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        'position' : alCorsaroLocation,
        'map' : map,
        'title' : 'Al Corsaro'
    });

//////////////////////////////////////////////Pop up containing address when marker is clicked
var popupContent = 'Ristorante Al Corsaro:<br>';
popupContent += 'Via Paina, 17<br>';
popupContent += '37018 Malcesine Verona<br>';
popupContent += 'Italy';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: popupContent,
  maxWidth: 200
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
});

}

function oasiMap() {
var oasiLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(45.80406, 10.842993);

var mapOptions = {
  'center' : oasiLocation,
  'zoom' : 17,
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('oasiMap'), mapOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        'position' : oasiLocation,
        'map' : map,
        'title' : 'Oasi Bar'
    });

//////////////////////////////////////////////Pop up containing address when marker is clicked
var popupContent = 'Hotel Oasi Beach:<br>';
popupContent += 'Via Gardesana, 510<br>';
popupContent += '37018 Malcesine Verona<br>';
popupContent += 'Italy';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: popupContent,
  maxWidth: 200
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
});

}


window.onload = function() {
scaligeroMap();
alCorsaroMap();
oasiMap();
};
```

So using this code scaligeroMap(); is displayed on the page which uses it but alCorsaroMap(); and oasiMap(); which are on a separate page are not displayed. If I put scaligeroMap(); at the bottom so that it executes last both alCorsaroMap(); & oasiMap(); will work but scaligeroMap(); won't. How do I make it so that they all display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the map element exists before trying to run code on an element that does not exist on that page.

You can do this on your window.onload function:

```
var scaligeroMapElement =  document.getElementById('scaligeroMap');
if (typeof(scaligeroMapElement) != 'undefined' && scaligeroMapElement != null)
{
    scaligeroMap();
}

var alCorsaroMapElement =  document.getElementById('alCorsaroMap');
if (typeof(alCorsaroMapElement) != 'undefined' && alCorsaroMapElement != null)
{
    alCorsaroMap();
}

var oasiMapElement =  document.getElementById('oasiMap');
if (typeof(oasiMapElement) != 'undefined' && oasiMapElement != null)
{
    oasiMap();
}
```

This is assuming each of your maps have different IDs.

If you have the jQuery included, you can just do:

```
if ($('#alCorsaroMap').length > 0) {
    oasiMap();
}
```